# Why are tangent vectors coordinate-dependent?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Why does the coordinate basis for $T_pM$ depend on the coordinate chart we are using? Any two charts containing $p$ agree on some neighborhood of $p$, so shouldn't we be able to find a basis for $T_pM$ that is coordinate-independent? For example, let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $p \in M$ that is contained in two charts $(U, \varphi)$, $(V, \psi)$. Let $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p\}$ be a coordinate basis for $T_pM$ with respect to $\varphi$. A basis vector acts on $f \in C^{\infty}M$ by $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p f = \frac{\partial (f \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}(p)$$ Similarly, if $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}|_p\}$ is a coordinate basis for $T_pM$ with respect to to $\psi$ then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}|_p (f) = \frac{\partial (f \circ \psi^{-1})}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}(p)$$ But the behavior $\varphi^{-1}$ and $\psi^{-1}$ both map to the same neighborhood of $p$ (the neighborhood can be assumed to be small enough). So why isn't $$\frac{\partial (f \circ \varphi)}{\partial x^i}(p) = \frac{\partial (f \circ \psi)}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}(p)$$

Comment: I think Pedro's answer misses the real source of your confusion, which seems to me to lie in the statement "Any two charts containing p agree on some neighborhood of p." What exactly is this supposed to mean? Just because $p\in M$ lies in both $U$ and $V$, that is, $p\in U\cap V$, does not mean $\phi(U\cap V)=\psi(U\cap V)$. In particular, it is need not be true that $\phi(p)=\psi(p)$.

Comment: I agree, but my confusion was that, suppose $\varphi(p) = a$ and $\psi(p) = b$. Then there is a neighborhood $U_a \ni a$ and a neighborhood $U_b \ni b$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(U_a) = \psi^{-1}(U_b)$. Since the derivations $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}$ act on a function $f$ by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f = \frac{\partial (f \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}$ (and similarly for the other derivation), then why aren't the two derivations equal (remembering that $\varphi^{-1}(U_a) = \psi^{-1}(U_b)$)?

Comment: ok, that does clarify what you had in mind, but you can now see the more precise reason why you were confused: in a word, you are forgetting the chain rule. In your notation, take $a=b=1$, $U_a=U_b=\mathbb{R}$, $\phi$ the identity on $\mathbb{R}$, $\psi$ half the identity, and $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. We certainly have $\phi^{-1}(U_a)=\psi^{-1}(U_b)$. But the derivative of $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ at $a=1$ is not equal to the derivative of $f\circ\psi^{-1}$ at $b=1$. I think you were forgetting to consider how the inverses map back through the manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because charts give *some* basis, why are you expecting it to be invariant? Consider say in $\Bbb R^2$ two independent vectors. This always give a basis for the tangent space at "any" point, but certainly differentiating a function in *different directions* gives different values. A coordinate choice gives $n$ directions to differentiate, but different choices give different values.

Comment: But the two maps $\varphi^{-1}$ and $\psi^{-1}$ both map to the same neighborhood. So why don't the derivations $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}$ agree on all $f \in C^{\infty}M$?

Comment: @JonathanGafar Try to follow your logic with a simple example, as I said. Take the chart $(x,y)$ for $\Bbb R^n$ and the chart $(x,x+y)$. These both map to $\Bbb R^n$, but give derivations in different directions. The point is that the tangent space is purely local information, it doesn't depend on the choice of an arbitrary neighbourhood, but of the germ of the $C^\infty$ functions at the point.

Comment: Thanks! The edited answer makes it clear for me now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question! You asked, "So why isn't
$$\frac{\partial (f \circ \varphi)}{\partial x^i}(p) = \frac{\partial (f \circ \psi)}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}(p)?  \ \ (*)$$"

The answer is that they ***ARE*** equal. Because, in the definition of the tangent space, we equate vectors $v$ in one coordinate, with $w$ in another local coordinates in $R^n$ exactly when one is the image of the differntial of the change of coordinate function, (and not when they are equal in the usual sense) i.e.

$$D(\varphi \circ \psi ^{-1})(v)= w $$

From this it follows that (*) says that we have the same tangent vector up there on the manifold.

$\varphi \circ \psi ^{-1}$ : change of coordinates from an open subset of $R^n$ to another

$v$: vector with initial position at, say q

$w$ : vector with initial position at $\hat{q}=\varphi \circ \psi ^{-1}(q)$, and equal to $D(\varphi \circ \psi ^{-1})(v).$

Note: Think of the open unit ball in $R^2$ as a manifold. Now, a chart of M, can be the identity from open ball to M. Another chart can be the rotation of the open ball around $0$, say 45 degrees. So, the tangent vector $\vec{e_1}$ at origin in the first coordinate is equal to the vector ${(1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)}$ at origin, and we must equate them since they must define the same tangent on M.